# Auxílio para criar o primeiro projeto android

Tags: android

Olá.

Não consigo criar o projeto para iniciar o estudo de android.

Segue um print da tela da criação do projeto no link do sendspace. Por favor vejam e me digam no que estou errando.

https://www.sendspace.com/file/o784cv

E um print das configurações do eclipse em relação ao caminho do sdk:

https://www.sendspace.com/file/vhkc8h

Aparece o erro:

> Project name must be specified >

Estou seguindo os post de:

http://www.felipesilveira.com.br/2010/04/criando-um-projeto-android-helloworld/

Comment: Poste mais detalhes do que está fazendo, não adicione somente links.

Comment: Você já tentou criá-lo no [tag:android-studio]? É bem mais fácil, ainda mais para quem está iniciando.

Answer (score 2):

Fala André,

Provavelmente esse erro no nome do projeto, deve ser porque você está iniciando ele com letra minúscula.

Mas eu aconselho você aposentar o Eclipse e instalar o Android Studio.

É o programa próprio do Android para trabalhar com projetos em Java, você pode fazer o download dele no link:

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

É infinitamente melhor pra trabalhar com Android, as formas de importar bibliotecas são muito mais simples, e eles o atualizam direto.

Qualquer dúvida que você tiver na instalação avisa aqui que a gente te ajuda.

Abraços.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a excelente sugestão do Leonardo,

Recomendo muito o curso Gratuito do Udacity que é feito por profissionais da Google, eles utilizam somente o Android Studio e ensinam bem explicadinho.

O curso é em formato de vídeo aulas, o único con é que alguns poucos vídeos não possuem legenda em português.

Segue [link](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837)